Gmail ignores RTL direction directives
I am sending HTML emails with explicit HTML attribute and style to make the text RTL.
But gmail seems to strip it out completely.
Example email body (HTML)
<html lang='he-IL' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head><meta name='Content-Language' content='he-IL' /></head>
<body align='right' dir='rtl' style='direction: rtl; text-align: right;'>
<small><i>הודעה זו נשלחה ב25/11/24 20:11 (IL)</i></small><br>המערכת ניסתה לקבוע בשבילך שיעור לזמן הרגיל שלך (יום שישי, 2024-12-06 14:40 (IL)) אך אין מספיק כסף בחשבונך. נא בבקשה להכנס ל <a style='color: #555555 !important; font-weight: bold;' href='https://gameready.co.il/pay/?student=Alon.Portnoy'>https://gameready.co.il/pay/?student=Alon.Portnoy</a> או ליצור קשר עם שירות לקוחות אם לדעתך משהו לא תקין<br>כדי להשבית התראות דוא`ל כמו זו, עבור אל <a href='https://gameready.co.il/settings' style='color: #555555 !important; font-weight: bold;'>ההגדרות</a> שלך.
</body>
</html>

If i render that code with a browser it correctly displays the RTL and alignment:

But the gmail recipient sees LTR text and aligned to left , indeed by looking at the HTML  received by the recipient , it seems that the RTL and right alignment directives have been stripped out completely.
Why is this? How to make it RTL? Thanks
EDIT: emails are sent automatically by code , not by gmail interface.
